# Read content from a URL, place into a textbox

Tags: c#

*I'm trying to read lines from a website and then, copy it into my `textBox2`.
`textBox1` will have a website's URL like `http://example.com`.
When I click on `button1` I'd like to read HTML content from the above URL, and please that info `textBox2`.
Should I use HtmlAgilityPack?
How can this be done?*

## 2 =================================================

So, for example, i copy this link into my "textBox1"
http://www.mineshaftersquared.com/server/DareCraft#

So, is there a way to make app copy everything from:

//*[@id="Plugins"]

to

//*[@id="rightInfo"]/section[2]/div/div[1]/table[2]

/this is XPath

/It don't have to in XPath, but this was the only way I could show.

Comment: Did you want the HTML in your textbox, or the human readable content?

Comment: As much as human-readable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install HtmlAgilityPack, you reference if from your project.

Read about [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.openread.aspx) class (`OpenRead` method), you probably want to use it to get the pages.

Here is a tutorial you might want to start with:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33798/HTTP-GET-with-NET-WebClient